# How to add and update objects into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to dynamically add an object to an array of objects, I have been trying to Destructuring the main object but it adds a number to the end of the parent array. This is what I have:

```
const [data, setData] = useState ([
 {
     _id:1,
     firstName:'Leo',
     lastName:'Miller',
     telephone:'+569273829',
     mail:'leo.miller@gmail.com',
     work:[
          {_id:1, startWorkDate:'01/01/2015', endWorkDate:'01/02/2017', work:'description...'},
          {_id:2, startWorkDate:'01/01/2018', endWorkDate:'01/02/2020', work:'description...'}
     ]
}];
```

I generate dynamically this object:

```
const value = {_id:3, startWorkDate:'01/01/2018', endWorkDate:'01/02/2020', work:'description...'}
```

I need to add it into data.work and after that update only the description of `work._id[3]`

I try with this function

```
const addNewWork = (value) => {
        let copyData = [...data, data[0].workExperience.push(value)]
        return setData(copyData)
    }
```

but for some reason doesn't add correctly the object. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array and not an object. Your statement

```
 let copyData = [...data, data[0].workExperience.push(value)]
```

is doing two things:

1. mutating the state by doing `push()`. Which is not the react way.
2. creating a new array. Also adding a new item to the array, but that is the new length of `data[0].workExperience`.

The return value of `Array.prototoype.push` is:

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

What you have to do is:

Make a copy of the array. Can use `...` (spread operator) here.
Make a  copy of the array object you want (first index). Try to add the object to its specific property `workExperience`.

```
const addNewWork = (value) => {
       let newData = [...data];
      let newWorkExperienceArray = 
       [...data[0].workExperience,value];
      
       let newDataFirstObject = {...data[0], workExperience : newWorkExperienceArray};
        newData[0] =  newDataFirstObject;
        return setData(newData)
    }
```

You can also update the property. I didn't find the relevant code in your question as to what I have to update so I didn't update anything in the third workExperience object.

**EDIT:** It seems in your code the property name is `work` and not `workExperience`. Please confirm. The above code uses `workExperience`, you can replace it by `work` if that is the case

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this simple function:

```
const addNewWork = (value) => {
   let updatedObj = data[0];
   updatedObj.work.push(value)
   
   // updates your object each time
   let copyData = [updatedObj]
   
   // adds a new object for each call
   // let copyData = [...data, updatedObj]
   return setData(copyData)
}
```

Now it updates the object in your state. If you want to add a new object for each call just uncomment `let copyData = [...data, updatedObj]` and comment out `let copyData = [updatedObj]`

Answer (score 0):

When you set state for array your setter is a quite bite different

```
setData(prevData => [...prevData, newItem]) // to add a single item to array

setData(prevData => newArray) // to replace entire array
```